# Wine - installing SW: JK: JA

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I have successfully installed Jedi Academy (well, at least I think so), but when I try to run it, it freezes at the intro screen. The screen where is the logo.

Only key that is working is ESC and when I press it, the game closes and it returns me to desktop. I need to reboot the laptop in order to get my normal resolution and functionality.

I downloaded all DLLs and other components for Wine, but the problem remains. I tried to install it via PlayOnLinux app, but I can't run it via cracked .exe file only through launcher and it asks me for CD.

If you know anything that could help I would appreciate it.

Comment: Are you double-clicking the EXE or are you using the terminal? If you run `wine /path/to/exe`, you'll get messages that you can paste into your question that might help resolve this. You should also read this. I think it has a fix: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1713

Answer (score 0):

I had no luck getting Jedi Academy to work with wine or PlayOnLinux (although I did with Jedi Knight), but the [openJK project](https://github.com/JACoders/OpenJK) did work, and works perfectly for me with Academy.

Skip down to the part of the website labeled "for players".